# How to remove matched words from string

Tags: java, string, replace

Suppose I have a string and I want to check if it contains the following words, then matched words should be removed.

The words are `‘PTE’, ‘LTD’, ‘PRIVATE’ and ‘LIMITED’`

I want to check it for both scenerios like if I have word.

```
String company = "xxx Basit xxx";  //xxx can be ‘PTE’, ‘LTD’, ‘PRIVATE’ and ‘LIMITED’
```

then output should be just `Basit`.

and if I have string like:

```
String company = "xxxBasitxxxMasoodxxx";
```

then output should be:

```
BasitMasood
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] str = {"PTE", "LTD", "PRIVATE", "LIMITED"};
String company = "PTE      Basit PTE";
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    company = company.replaceAll(str[i], "");
}
System.out.println(company.replaceAll("\\s","")); //remove whitespaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**String#replaceAll(regex, str)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    String company = "PRIVATE Basit PTE";
    System.out.println(company.replaceAll("PTE|LTD|PRIVATE|LIMITED", ""));
```

output:

Basit

Answer (score 0):

```
String company = //your string
company.replaceAll("PTE|LTD|PRIVATE|LIMITED", "");
```

Comment: `String.replace(String)` doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

`"PTEBasitLTDMasoodPRIVATE".replaceAll("PTE|LTD|PRIVATE|LIMITED","");`

will result in

> BasitMasood

Comment: if i have string like `PTEBasitLTDMasoodLimited` then `replaceAll(xxx, "")`..... ? `xxx can be four words that i mentioned`

Comment: @Basit so you have to call this once for every word. You could also use a regex `"PTE|LTD|PRIVATE|LIMITED"` instead of "xxx".